# Sistemas de ecuaciones no lineales en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

Tengo la siguiente inquietud con sistema de ecuaciones no lineales en **python**:

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve as fs
def nonlinear(z):
    '''Solve a sistems  2x2 not linear
    '''
    x, y = z[0], z[1]
    f1 = (x**2)+(y**2)-2*(4.41*x+2.68*y)+25.59
    f2 = (x**2)+(y**2)-2*(3.23*x+2.1*y)+14.49
    return [f1, f2]
```

¿Cómo puedo encontrar las múltiples soluciones del sistema anterior con el código que realicé?

Por que si ejecuto la función anterior con unos valores iniciales me arrojaría sólo una solución:

```
x, y = fs(nonlinear, [1,1])
print(x,y)
3.38998152293 2.67210655679
```

Todas las soluciones que tiene el sistema son las siguientes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que deberías desarrollar más tu pregunta. No comprendo qué son `f1` y `f2`. Qué tipo de sistema es ese y cómo quieres resolverlo. Si a lo que te refieres es a obtener las dos raíces de cada incógnita, deberías resolver de forma explícita para las dos raíces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fsolve` utiliza un enfoque numérico de optimización para encontrar **una solución** a la ecuación dada. En teoría no es posible (o no hay un método general) con SciPy hacer esto, en la práctica es posible hacerlo numéricamente si conocemos el número de soluciones y jugando con los valores iniciales, que en variables físicas tenemos muchas veces acotados. No obstante, dada la variabilidad de los sistemas, esto no siempre va a ser fácil o incluso posible.

En este caso creo que es más simple usar un enfoque analítico con SymPy en vez de uno numérico con SciPy:

```
from sympy import var, solve


x, y = var('x y')

f1 = (x**2)+(y**2)-2*(4.41*x+2.68*y)+25.59
f2 = (x**2)+(y**2)-2*(3.23*x+2.1*y)+14.49

sols = solve((f1, f2), (x, y))
```

Soluciones:

```
>>> sols
>>> [(3.38998152293488, 2.67210655678766),
     (3.78069409020719, 1.87720857509572)]
```

Comment: pero aún siguen faltando soluciones de ese sistema... yo solucioné el sistema en un softaware en internet y encuentro que el sistema tiene 4 soluciones reales. En python puedo hacer eso o sólo lo que  usted hizo ? (Observe la imagen que subí en donde se muestra las posibles soluciones del sistema)

Comment: ¿Andrés estás seguro que los valores de `x = (8.82+sqrt(1.58410))/2` y `x = (8.82+sqrt(4.16175))/2` son soluciones válidas para el sistema? Estoy algo limitado al no tener un pc a mano y puede que me equivoque, pero según WolframAlpha las soluciones son las que se obtienen con SymPy.

Comment: No estás equivocado, tienes la razón en cuanto a lo que dices. Esas soluciones no satisfacen el sistema. Eso era lo que buscaba, ya lo implementé en el algoritmo que estoy elaborando y está funcionando pero, noto que el costo computacional es muy alto cuando se solucionan esos sistemas. Tienes alguna recomendación para mejorar el tiempo de ejecución ?